# Positioning a slide relative to a grandparent whilst moving the parent slider (Image carousel)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edit:** I've added a solution that uses JS to get the grandparent's width and then sets the slide width (which allows the slide and the slider to be positioned absolutely), but I'm still interested if this can be done with css

---

Original question

So I'm trying to make an image carousel. I've absolutely positioned the slides in relation to their grandparent (the white `.dummy-page`), so that I can make sure that the correct number of slides (and margins) are visible. It looks like this:

[image: Slider image]

The problem is that to move the `.slider` (the parent with the red border) that contains the `.slides`s I need to position it absolutely. But this breaks the sizing of each `.slide`, which are set to 30% of `.dummy-page`, but become 30% of the `.slider`.

I thought using transform might help (as I don't have to then position the parent absolutely), but the same happens (uncomment line 9 in the JS to see the effect)

Would appreciate other ideas on how to position/size the slides, because I think my approach is fundamentally flawed

Thanks!

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/RwJvmgQ?editors=0110)

```js
const moveLeft = () => {
  const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
  const slide = document.querySelector('.slide');
  const slideWidth = slide.offsetWidth;
  const slideLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(slide).left);
  const offset = slideWidth + slideLeft;
  
  // addStyle(slider, {'left': `${offset}px`});  
  // slider.style.transform = `translateX(${30}px)`;
}

const addStyle = (element, style) => {
    for (const property in style) element.style[property] = style[property];
}

moveLeft();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --slide-width: 30%;
  --slide-height: 15rem;
  --num-slides: 5;
  --visible-slides: 3;
  --slide-margin: calc( (100% - var(--visible-slides) * var(--slide-width)) / (var(--visible-slides) + 1) );
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.dummy-page {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
}

.slider {
  display: inline-flex;

  /*   Each slide has width and a margin-right, + 1 LHS margin */
  width: calc(var(--num-slides) * (var(--slide-width) + var(--slide-margin)) + var(--slide-margin));
  height: var(--slide-height);

  margin-top: 2rem;

  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--slide-height);
  width: var(--slide-width);
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.slide-1 {
  left: var(--slide-margin);
}
.slide-2 {
  left: calc(var(--slide-margin) * 2 + var(--slide-width))
}
.slide-3 {
  left: calc(var(--slide-margin) * 3 + var(--slide-width) * 2);
}

.slide-4 {
  left: calc(var(--slide-margin) * 4 + var(--slide-width) * 3);
}

.slide-5 {
  left: calc(var(--slide-margin) * 5 + var(--slide-width) * 4);
}

.btn-container { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: .5rem;
  padding: .8rem 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy-page">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
      <div class="slide slide-4"></div>
      <div class="slide slide-5"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="btn-container">
      <div class="btn left">Left</div>
      <div class="btn right">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**JS (almost working) solution**

I added an additional slider container here for ease of use later, but I'm grabbing the grandparent element's width using JS (which is annoyingly out by 10px), and then setting the slide width. This means that both the slide and the slider can be positioned absolutely

[codepen](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/yLEZddp?editors=1111)

```
const initSlider = () => {
  const pageWidth = document.querySelector('.slider-container').offsetWidth;
  
  const numSlides = parseInt(getCssVariable('--num-slides'));
  const slideWidth = pageWidth / numSlides;

  setCssVariable('--slide-width', `${slideWidth}px`);
 
}

const getCssVariable = (name) => {
  return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name);
}

const setCssVariable = (name, value) => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, value);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initSlider());
```